# Dialog statement

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am trying to write a code which has dialog  including such as toggle button, edittext, pushbutton, popupmenu, etc. I have no problem with all, but when the dialog screen which is named "Find Name" is seen on Map Window, I could not do something without closing dialog screen. **I want to work with "Find Name" dialog screen and also use all the tools in MapInfo such as "Radius Select", "Grabber", etc. without closing dialog screen.** How to do either using MapInfo tools and appearing "Find Name" dialog screen on the Map Window at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the screen close or does it go behind the active window?

Comment: I think this might be helpful.Download visual studio and use it's GUI builder. You can find a lot of example online. You can call other application from mapinfo using *Run Program* command. Use mapbasic reference guide for more help. Search Integrated Mapping in the guide. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a floating kind of window like the new Layer Control and the TableList window, you need to create your window/dialog using for example .NET.

The dialogs created thru MapBasic are modal and prevents the user from using the MI Pro while the dialog is open on the screen.

So create a window in .NET, compile that into a dll and use the Declare Method statement that was added to MapBasic 9.5 to make this .NET method available to your MapBasic application

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your reply. I see that. If you have an example about .NET, could you please give a sample application using .NET to create a window? Thanks and regards...

Comment: Have a look at the NamedViews sample code that comes with MapBasic: Samples\DOTNET\NAMEDVIEWS\